# Getting Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rdlc

Dear All Please Help I'm getting this error when I want to pass parameter in RDLC Report. To View Images [image]

This is My code Please help

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //string query = @"Select * from Studentsinfor";
            var data = db.Database.SqlQuery<StudentsInfo>(query);
            ReportViewer1.SizeToReportContent = true;
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("IDCards.rdlc");
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            ReportDataSource ds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", data);
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(ds);
            this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;

            /* begin added part */

            // get absolute path to Project folder
            string path = new Uri(Server.MapPath("~/Photos")).AbsoluteUri; // adjust path to Project folder here

            // set above path to report parameter
            var parameter = new ReportParameter[1];
            parameter[0] = new ReportParameter("ImagePath", path); // adjust parameter name here
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameter);
            /* end of added part */

            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Comment: Try installing package `Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms` with version `14.0.0.0`, also with `Microsoft.RdlcDesigner` package if you're using VS 2017.

Comment: Thanks a lot worked